# Early Expansion of Variables in Recipes

Tags: gnu-make, variable-expansion

I know about the distinction between the two kinds of variables in GNU Make.

I am currently writing a build system where certain variables are defined in sub directories (e.g., VERSION). To make the life simpler for authors of subdirectories, I do not want to force them to make their variables globally unique. I also would like to avoid recursive make.

My problem is now that I need a way to provide some simple library targets that expand these common variables when the target is defined. As a simple example:

```
FOO := Bar
PHONY: $(FOO)
$(FOO):
    @echo $(FOO)

FOO := Definitely not Bar

PHONY: test2
test2: Bar
    @echo $(FOO)
```

I would need the output of `make test2` to be

```
Bar
Definitely not Bar
```

I could, of course, use a temporary variable to force the expansion of FOO in the first rule, but then I need a way to reliably define a new temporary variable. Is there a way to expand a target, e.g. using eval?

edit: Made the curious expansion of FOO more clear in the example code.

Comment: Are you aware that also `make Bar`  does yield `Definitely not Bar` ?

Comment: Yes. Because the whole Makefile is read before the variables are subtituted in the recipes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if you simply want [target-specific variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html),
e.g.

**Makefile**

```
.PHONY: Bar test2

Bar: FOO := Bar
Bar:
    @echo $(FOO)

test2: FOO := Definitely not Bar
test2: Bar
    @echo $(FOO)
```

which runs like:

```
$ make test2
Bar
Definitely not Bar
```

(Note that `.PHONY`, like all special targets, begins with `.`)

Answer (score 0):

You can write some nicely functional code (pun intended) using `$(eval …)`. You get to write closures, and decide what gets expanded when.

Consider this variable:

```
define rule =
PHONY: ${FOO}
${FOO}:
        @echo $$@ ${FOO}
endef
```

Nothing strange here. But look what happens when we pass it to *eval*:

```
FOO := Bar
$(eval ${rule})
```

We'd better look at that last line in detail.

- *make* expands `$(eval ${rule})`

  - First it expands `${rule}`

    - `$$` expands to `$`
    - *All* occurences of `${FOO}` are replaced by `Bar`
    - leaving us with this text:
      `PHONY: Bar`
      `Bar:`
         `@echo $@ Bar`
      Can you see how the current value of `${FOO}` has been baked into the recipe?
  - Now the block of *make* syntax is passed to `$(eval)`

    - *Make* creates the new rule as a side effect of the *eval*
  - The expansion of the *eval* though is empty.

Nice.

```
FOO := Dead
$(eval ${rule})

FOO := Beef
$(eval ${rule})
```

You aren't very far away from eschewing global variables in favour of local parameters:

```
$(call makerule,Dead)
$(call makerule,Beef)
```

Gotta be a good thing, hasn't it?

[AFAICR *eval* didn't work very well in *make* 3.81, so use at least version 3.82]